# How to create a sails.js skeleton so I can quickly build new apps with common goals?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sass, sails.js, mariadb

This is more for some fun and playing around with, but hopefully should produce something useful.

I would like to extend sails.js framework so that when I generate a new app using 'sails new project-name' it will already have a lot of previous configurations or modules added. For example, with every project I would probably intend to use SASS. If you have had to setup SASS with sails before you will know it has a few bits of configuration to do first. It would be advantageous to not have to repeat this with each new project.

In short some things I would like to achieve upon creating each new project:

- Get SASS configured
- Generate multiple SASS partial files, such as _buttons.scss, _forms.scss
- Include SASS mixings within certain SASS files
- Include configuration and set up to use multiple databases like mongoDB and MariaDB (Much more complex I imagine)

Thanks

Comment: The [sails gitter room](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails) is also a good place to chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Balderdash we do this all the time to quickly spin up certain "types" of application.

You can fork https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-new and customize it to call additional generators that you can create using `ejs` templates.

I created a module called `sails-generate-entities` which you can see in use here: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/blob/master/index.js. For this sails extension, you'd call `sails generate permissions-api` and all those files would be added to the project. Your fork of `sails-generate-new` could include a call to a custom generator such as this.

Comment: Where abouts would I customize it to call generators and also how do I create generators?